# Python Request Package Close Connection Method Does not Work

Tags: python, rest, post, jupyter-notebook, request

it is the first time that I am working with a REST API in a jupyter notebook and I don't know what I am doing wrong here. When I try to execute the following code in a cell, the cell runs forever without throwing any errors. First I did not include the close method from the request package, but then I thought the problem might be the open connection. However including the close method also did not help. Do you know what could be the reason?

```
api_key = "exampletoken"
header = {'authorization':"Bearer {}".format(api_key)}
payload = {}
r = request.post('exampleurl', headers = header, data = payload)
r.close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*runs forever without throwing any errors.*

By default `requests` does not timeout, so it can wait infinite amount of time. This might cause behavior you described and mean server did not respond. To figure if that is cause, please set `timeout` for example

```
r = request.post('exampleurl', headers = header, data = payload, timeout=180)
```

would raise Exception after 180 seconds (i.e. 3 minutes) if it do not get response. If you want to know more about timeouts in `requests` I suggest reading [realpython.com tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-requests/#timeouts)